# Multiple Checkbox select one at a time using React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

Hi guys I'm using react hook form for multiple checkbox, Currently all checkbox can be selected.
Any idea how can I select checkbox one at a time?

```
 const formMethods = useForm<BookingSourcesForm>({
    defaultValues: { bookingSources: [] },
  });

  const { fields, append } = useFieldArray<BookingSourcesForm>({
    control: formMethods.control,
    name: 'bookingSources',
  });


    {fields.map((field, index) => {
                    return (
                      <HStack align="center" justify="space-between" w="100%">
                              <Controller
                                name={`bookingSources.${index}.IsDefault` as const}
                                control={control}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                  <Checkbox
                                    isChecked={field.value}
                                    onChange={(e) => {
                                      field.onChange(e.currentTarget.checked);
                                    }}
                                  />
                                )}
                              />
                       )
                    }
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If only one box should be able to picked you should use a RadioGroup instead.
See: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/radio/usage

Comment: Thanks for that,  I'm just following the client figma design. :D
btw I already solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
       onChange={(value) => {
                getValues(`bookingSources`)?.forEach((booking, idx) => {
    setValue(`bookingSources.${idx}.IsDefault` as `bookingSources.0.IsDefault`, false);
                });
    
                field.onChange(value);
       }}
```

Comment: Whilst the code-only answer solves the original problem, it doesn't provide any explanation as to why this works. Please, consider adding more context and detailed explanation to the answer.